# Jquery - Hide a ID unless another ID is visible

Tags: jquery, hide, visible

here is my script, Im not sure what i am missing to make this work, this would help with so many issues. thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnUpdate1_div, #btnAddress1_div, #btnUpdate2_div, #btnAddress2_div").hide();
    $("#StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").hide();
    if ("#StepArea_warningAddressBook") {
        $("#StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I would also recomend using css to hide the divs initially: `#btnUpdate1_div, #btnAddress1_div, #btnUpdate2_div, #btnAddress2_div { display: none }`. Using javascript to hide them will likely cause an initial flicker where they are visible before being hidden since the js takes a while to load.

Comment: A  quick Google search "jQuery Check if visible" or "jQuery check if hidden" would have saved writing a question and gave you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the answer I had to change how I asked the question.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($("#StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").is(":visible")){
 $("#StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").hide();
}else if (
    $("#StepArea_warningAddressBook").is(':visible')) {
        $("#StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").show();
}
```

});

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.is(':hidden')` or `.is(':visible')` like following:

```
if( $("#StepArea_warningAddressBook").is(':hidden') ) {  // change condition what you want
  $("#StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").show();
}
```

Related refs:

- **[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)**
- **[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)**
- **[:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)**

Comment: Thanks, I tried something a little different, it seemed to work, accept I cant get the #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem to show if StepArea_warningAddressBook is val = 1

Comment: if ($("#StepArea_warningAddressBook").val("0")) {
  $("#StepArea_lnkAddresBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").hide();
  } if {
  ($("#StepArea_warningAddressBook").val("1"))
  $("#StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem").show();
  }
 });

Comment: Well it shows everything perfectly like it should if #StepArea_warningAddressBook = 1. But if its 0=off it still shows #StepArea_lnkAddressBook which should be hidden. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Cam but jsfiddle is uncomplete. please complete it will full html and js

Comment: @Cam where do you get the `.val()` there is no `input`?

Comment: its very close, I should explain why StepArea_warningAddressBook appears if you have an invalid address, if you put in your address this div doesnt show at all in the code, if the script doesnt find StepArea_warningAddressBook then StepArea_lnkAddressBook, #StepArea_linkToAddressBookItem should be hidden completely.. Your continual patients is appreciated.